# Integration of differential equation with orthogonality constraint

Tags: ode, constrained-optimization, runge-kutta, constraints

Lets say I have a system of differential equations which has the form
$$\dot{C}_{\alpha,\beta,m} = f_{\alpha,\beta,m}(C_{\alpha,\beta,1},\ldots,C_{\alpha,\beta,N};t).$$
The $f$s are some functions of time and of the $C$s. The exact form is not important.

In principle, this can be solved with a simple RK4 algorithm.
However, there is now the additional (orthogonality) constraint 
$$\sum_{\alpha,\beta}C_{\alpha,\beta,m}^* C_{\alpha,\beta,n} \stackrel{!}{=} \delta_{m,n},$$ which should hold at any time $t$. The star denotes the complex conjugate.

My question is now, how this constraint can be implemented in my integration scheme/RK 4 algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, one cannot expect rk4 to maintain quadratic invariants of the system, it simply doesn't do that. Methods that *do* maintain specific invariants have to be specially devised — this usually goes by the name of *geometric integration*. Symplectic integrators are the most common kind of these methods, although not for your problem.

See, for example, the book [*Geometric Numerical Integration* by Hairer, Wanner, Lubich](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-30666-8), or [the notes *Solving Differential Equations on Manifolds* by Hairer (free online)](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly-sde-mani.pdf).

Probably the simplest way to incorporate the constraint is to project the approximate solution onto the constraint manifold ("Projection methods", Example 1.3, p. 21 in the Hairer notes above). Given a system of ODEs 
$$ \dot X = f(t, X), \qquad X^*X=I, $$
define $\pi(X)$ to be the closest unitary matrix to $X$. If $X = UH$ is the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of $X$, then $\pi(X) = U$.

The simplest is to project onto the constraint manifold after each RK step, $\tilde X_{n+1} = \pi(X_{n+1})$. The second simplest is to rewrite the ODE as 
$$ \dot X = f(t, \pi(X)), $$
which will incorporate the projection into the RK substeps. (This doesn't actually modify the ODE because $\pi(X)=X$ for any exact solution.)

Beyond this, the constraint manifold is called a [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold), and there already seem to be some number of articles on google scholar on numerical integration on Stiefel manifolds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there also a way using Lagrange multipliers? I think this is used in the Car-Parrinello method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car%E2%80%93Parrinello_method Do you now something about this way of treating the problem?

Comment: @Merlin1896 I don't know.