# Projection on Stiefel manifold after integration step

Tags: ode, constrained-optimization, runge-kutta, constraints

A few days ago, [I asked how constraints like](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/integration-of-differential-equation-with-orthogonality-constraint) $A^T A = I$ can be implemented if one wishes to integrate differential equations of the form $\dot{A}=f(A,t)$. Kirill was so kind to point out that a projection step on the Stiefel manifold after one integration step (for example after one Runge Kutta step) is sufficient to get the correct solution. This projection $\pi(A)$ can be found via the polar decomposition of the matrix $A$.

Now my question is, why a projection after one full RK step is sufficient. If one uses, for example, a 4th order RK method then intermediate sampling points are used. These intermediate points do not necessarily fulfil the constraint $A^T A = I$. Why do I not have to reorthogonalise the matrix A after one intermediate step but only after a full RK4 step? Is this still a valid 4th order method or is there an additional error introduced because the constraint is not fulfilled at the intermediate sampling points?

Papers like the one from [Higham (1997)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.140.434) seem to indicate that it is perfectly fine to use any one-step method between the projections on the manifold and no accuracy is lost. I do not see the reason why this is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a matter of fact, if you project each Runge-Kutta stage you will (in general) **reduce the method to first order accuracy**; this effect is similar to the order reduction that can occur due to boundary condition implementations.  To explain it briefly, notice that the first stage of the method is just a forward Euler step, which gives a first-order accurate approximation of the solution.  Hence it will be $O(\Delta t^2)$ away from the constraint manifold, and by projecting you introduce an $O(\Delta t^2)$ error that won't go away.  For a more detailed explanation see [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0916072).

So projecting only after a full step is probably best.